# How to get Property from Spring Context in a pojo not managed by spring?

Tags: spring, properties, pojo

I have a property file that is configured within spring context xml file. I load values from the file fine. 
I am trying to load a property from that property file in a regular pojo which is not spring managed. Since Spring has already loaded that property, i was wondering if there is a way to get the value instead of me having to load the property file manually?

Comment: Why not have the pojo be managed?  In particular, if you're going to have to get your hands on the Spring container to get to the properties, why not just manage the pojo?

Comment: Can you not just get a hold of the Spring context and access the property that way?  I'm sure they is a way to get it form the property configurer.  If not you could always have a simple pojo that IS Spring managed with the injected property.  Then in your pojo, access that pojo to get the properties.  It's not elegant, but  would get the job done.

Comment: @chad/@Justin, within a method, i need to get the property value only if certain condition hold true, and creating a field for that felt like a overkill even in the case if the bean is spring managed.

Comment: @bond How is the property resolved inside the container? Is it a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Comment: @Boris, yes i used PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the Spring context in a static way if your pojo is not managed by Spring.

**Add a bean to your application xml:**

```
<bean id="StaticSpringApplicationContext" class="com.package.StaticSpringApplicationContext"/>
```

**Create a class:**

```
public class StaticSpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware  {
    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

      public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        CONTEXT = context;
      }

      public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
        return CONTEXT.getBean(beanName);
      }

}
```

**Then you can acces any Spring bean from your POJO using:**

```
StaticSpringApplicationContext.getBean("yourBean")
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more modern approach, that uses annotations and implements generics you can use this version, build upon Wickramarachi response:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StaticSpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        StaticSpringApplicationContext.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(requiredType);
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(String beanName, Class<T> requiredType) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanName, requiredType);
    }

}
```

Usage is as follow:

```
SpringJPAPersistenceChannel bean = StaticSpringApplicationContext.getBean(MyBean.class);
```