# Bootstrap camel in spring web application

Tags: apache-camel

I'm creating a application with Spring-jersey-camel. I wanted to expose my jersey layer and internally invoke camel routes to invoke resources.

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <packageScan>
    <package>com.company.myapp.camel</package>
    <excludes>**.*</excludes>
    <includes>*Routes.java</includes>
  </packageScan>
</camelContext>
```

MyRoutes.java

```
@Component
public final class MyRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

      from("direct:getOrdersData").validate(body().isNotNull())
      .log("Camel to get orders")
      .to("restlet:http://localhost:8081/ordersapp/rest/order/123");    
  }
}
```

OrderResourceImpl.java

```
@Component
@Path("/orderLookup")
public class ReservationResources {

  @org.apache.camel.produce
  ProducerTemplate producer;

  public void setProducer(ProducerTemplate producer) throws Exception {
     this.producer = producer;
  }

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Path("{orderId}")
  public Response orderLookup(@PathParam("orderId") final long orderrId){
    Response r = Response.noContent().build();

    //Producer is null. throws nullPointerException
    String order= producer.requestBody("direct:getOrdersData", orderId, String.class);
    r = Response.ok().entity(reservation).build();
    return r;
  }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? or how to inject myRoute/ProducerTemplate im my orderResourceImpl.java. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two Options,
If ReservationResources is a spring bean then, Inject the Camel Context into it and create a ProducerTemplate from that

```
ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
```

If `ReservationResources` is not a spring bean then get the Camel Context via a static method https://stackoverflow.com/a/13633109/3696510 and then create the ProducerTemplate.

```
ProducerTemplate template = StaticSpringApplicationContext.getBean("camelContext").createProducerTemplate()
```

Also if you do use that `StaticSpringApplicationContext` mentioned in the link, I would add this method to it.

```
public static <T> T getBean(String beanName, Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) CONTEXT.getBean(beanName,clazz);
}
```